# How to write the equilibrium states of the model in term of paramters?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have following modified SI model for epidemics:

$$
\frac{dS}{dt}=-kIS+b
$$
$$
\frac{dI}{dt}= kIS-aI 
$$

Now as we know that at equilibrium state $$\frac{dS}{dt}=0$$ and $$\frac{dI}{dt} = 0$$
Considering this, we can get $I=\frac{b}{kS}$ from $\frac{dS}{dt}=0$ while $ I=0$ and $S=\frac{a}{k}$ from $\frac{dI}{dt} =0$

Now my question is, how can I get $I=\frac{b}{kS}$ in terms of only parameters $(a, b$ and $k)$?
My next question is related to writing identifying the various equilibrium states. For instance, one of them I believe is $(S, I=0)$. What are other possible equilibrium states? Best regards

Comment: You have two equations and two variables. Solve and conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dS}{dt}=0 \Rightarrow -kIS+b = 0 \Rightarrow I = \frac{b}{kS}.$$
$$\frac{dI}{dt}=0 \Rightarrow  kIS-aI = 0 \Rightarrow S = \frac{a}{k} \vee I =0.$$

If $I=0$, then $b = 0$. In this case, we have infinite equilibria points:

$$\begin{cases}I = 0\\S = s, ~\forall s \in \mathbb{R} \end{cases}$$

Setting $s=0$, then $I=S=0$ is an equilibrium point if and only if $b=0$.

If $S = \frac{a}{k}$, then:

$$I = \frac{b}{kS} = \frac{b}{k\frac{a}{k}} = \frac{b}{a}.$$

In this case you have only one equilibrium point expressed as function of parameters $a$, $b$ and $k$, that is:

$$\begin{cases}I = \frac{b}{a}\\S = \frac{a}{k}\end{cases}$$

**Addition**
When you solve $\frac{dI}{dt}=0$, you get:

$$kIS-aI = 0 = I(kS-a) = 0$$

In this case the equation is satisfied when $I = 0$ or when $(kS-a = 0)$. Let's focus on the first case, and move to the equation $\frac{dS}{dt}=0$:
$$-kIS+b = 0 \Rightarrow -k(0)S+b = b  = 0.$$

This means that $I$ can be $0$ when $b = 0$. Nothing is required for $S$. Then $S$ can be any real number, say $S = s$. Let's try!
Take for example $I=0$, $b=0$ and $S=10$. Then:
$$
\begin{cases}
-kIS+b = 0 \Rightarrow -k \cdot 0 \cdot 10+0 = 0\\
kIS-aI = 0 \Rightarrow k \cdot 0 \cdot 10 - a \cdot 0 = 0
\end{cases}
$$
Then, any couple $I=0, S=s$ is an equilibrium when $b=0$.

Comment: Thank you dear for your kind explanation. Now I am surely clearly understand the equilibrium states of the system. But can you please clarify your point how I=0 and b=0, will lead to infinite equilibrium points. and what is s (small S). Your answer really helped me. Regards.

Comment: @MazharHussain you are welcome! please, check the addition to my answer for a better explanation.

Comment: Thank you Sir, now I absolutely get it. Regards...

Answer (score 1):

In the following I assume all parameters to be strictly positive. Setting the second equation to zero results in

$k I S - a I = 0$

This implies that either (Case 1) $I_S=0$ or (Case 2) $S_S=\frac{a}{k}$. Setting the first equation to zero results in $KI_SS_S=b$. For Case 1, this implies that $0=b$, which is a contradiction if $b>0$. This implies that there are no steady states with $I_S=0$.

For Case 2, we get $KI_SS_S=b\Rightarrow kI_S\frac{a}{k}=b\Rightarrow I_S=\frac{b}{a}$. Thus, the only steady state of your system is $(I_s,S_s)^T=(\frac{b}{a},\frac{a}{k})^T$.

In summary, you set the ODEs to zero and arrive at a system of equations. By solving this system of equations for the states, you arrive at the steady-states. Depending on the specific set of ODEs, you might have to split your analysis into cases (as done here). And remember: you might end up with zero, one, or more steady-states.